# Mobile print format customization in mobile application

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-mobile, zebra-printers

I want to print a receipt containing text from MC75 [Windows mobile 6] and using a bluetooth printer (Zebra ).

I have a code like this: is working fine. But I want to change my print format

```
Private Sub SendZplOverBluetooth(ByVal theBtMacAddress As [String])
        Try

            Dim thePrinterConn As ZebraPrinterConnection = New BluetoothPrinterConnection(theBtMacAddress)
            thePrinterConn.Open()
            Dim zplData As [String] = "^XA^FO50,20^A0N,25,25^FD TestData.^FS^XZ"

            thePrinterConn.Write(Encoding.[Default].GetBytes(zplData))
            Thread.Sleep(500)

            thePrinterConn.Close()
        Catch e As Exception
            MsgBox("Error " & e.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

This will print "TestData". I want to make my print format like this:

```
    Event Service
    ONsite Delivery

StandNo:

ITEM            Quantity
-------------------------
AB               1
BC               2
---------Nothing-----------
all goods are received
---------------------
Date :
```

So how can I write code for this? I appreciate your immediate help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Looking thru the ZPL II Programming Guide I recommend to use the FieldBlock operator:

^FBw,l,,  w=block width in dots, l=maximum number of lines in block (rest of possible args see Programmers Guide).
The \& starts a new line

In ZPL II:

```
^XA
^CF0,30,30^FO25,50
^FB250,4,,
^FD
    Event Service\&
    ONsite Delivery\&
\&
StandNo:\&
\&
ITEM            Quantity\&
-------------------------\&
AB               1\&
BC               2\&
---------Nothing-----------\&
all goods are received\&
---------------------\&
Date : ^FS
^XZ

Dim zplData As [String] = "^XA^CF0,30,30^FO25,50^FB250,4,,^FD"
zplData = zplData+"    Event Service\&"
zplData = zplData+"    ONsite Delivery\&"
zplData = zplData+"\&"
... 
zplData = zplData+"^XZ"
...
```

Comment: does this cover a variable number of items?

Comment: it depends... You may write a function that takes an array of strings and then iterate thru this array when building zplData string. You may need to adjust the ^FB command to 'reserve' enough lines for the block (number of fixed lines plus number of strings in array). But this are very basic questions and solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Zebra Designer to generate a Master label. Make a print of that and Select "File" aß Output. You then get the zpl-code in this File. With this Code you can work and customize it like you want to.